# Is there a way to import Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to Azure Automation so it can be used in Powershell runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

I am trying to simplify while increasing security when I access Azure SQL databases in a Powershell workbook in Azure Automation.

I can currently query the required databases using the following connection and then supplying SQL Authentication based connection string.

```
$DatabaseConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$DatabaseConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $($SQLServer); Database = $($DBName); User ID = $($DBUser); Password = $($DBPass);"
```

However, my preference would be to use the new Managed Identities to authenticate the SQL client connection so that I no longer have to enable SQL Authentication and then store the admin credentials somewhere. So far I have been unable to find a way to use the new and recommended replacement for System.Data.SqlClient (being Microsoft.Data.SqlClient)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct PowerShell module for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which we can import to our Azure Automation account. You might have to create a custom PowerShell module for it with valid module structure and then import it to use.

Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/MartinHBA/86c6014175758a07b09fa7bb76ba8e27). However, [this](https://gist.github.com/MartinHBA/86c6014175758a07b09fa7bb76ba8e27) particular one is not in the valid module structure to import as a custom module in Azure Automation.